# Rails3 Whenever not working from cron, but perfectly from terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cron, centos5, whenever

Using Whenever 0.7.3, Rails 3.2.2, Ruby 1.9.3, Passenger 3.0.11 on a CentOS 5.6 server (I'm not using rvm). The problem is that the cron jobs created by whenever are clearly executed, I can see them in the Cron log, however they don't actually execute the Rails code. If I copy the cron code and paste it in the terminal it works as expected and does.

The code to be executed:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  #Delete all items that haven't been updated for 2 hours or more
  def self.cron_job
    SomeModel.destroy_all(updated_at < ?", 2.hours.ago])
  end
end
```

The schedule.rb:

```
set :output, "/var/log/cron"

every 1.day, :at => '4:45 am' do
  runner "SomeModel.cron_job"
end
```

Which generated the following cron (output crontab -l):

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: site_name
45 4 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/user/domains/site_name && script/rails runner -e production '\''SomeModel.cron_job'\'' >> /var/log/cron 2>&1'
# End Whenever generated tasks for: site_name
```

If I check the following morning I find this in the cron log:

```
Apr 14 04:45:01 node1 crond[9155]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/user/domains/site_name && script/rails runner -e production '\''SomeModel.cron_job'\'' >> /var/log/cron 2>&1')
```

However the items that should have been deleted are still in the database. If I copy the code cron is supposed to execute (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd ... 2>&1' and execute it from the terminal then the items are removed as expected.

Also when I execute the code manually from the terminal there are no errors, in the cron log i see the following:

```
from script/rails:5:in 'require'
from script/rails:5
from script/rails:5:in 'require'
from script/rails:5
```

At moments where several cron jobs are executed this "error(?)" is printed only once in the log.

Is there a difference between executing something from a cronjob or entering the code in the terminal? Why can there be a difference and how do I ensure that it also works from the cronjob? Also is the log output supposed to be an error, it's not telling me much unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok solved it now. The problem was that I had both a Ruby in /usr/bin and a Ruby in /usr/local/bin.

I've deleted the ruby in /usr/bin and added the right path variable (PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin") to the crontab. Everything working as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't set the environment properly.  If you're in development setting:

```
whenever --set environment=development
```

will set the environment to development

Comment: Sorry then, not being in the right environment is a common mistake I thought to bring up

Comment: Thanks and no problem. I've added the Passenger version to the original question, makes it more clear that it's the production environment I'm talking about.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone reading this in the future, the above code should be run at the command line rather than placed in a file.

Answer (score 0):

For future Googlers: I had this exact same problem, although mine was solved very differently...

I logged the output by putting `set :output,'./cronOutput.txt'` in my `schedule.rb` file, and kept getting `No JavaScript runtine found` as the output error. So I went and installed the [execjs](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/) and [therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) gems. Everything started working immediately afterwards.

My project was still in development, so I did have to follow Steve's advice (somewhat) and include `set :environment, "development"` in my `schedule.rb` as well in order to query my tables.

Hope this helps anyone else out!